# The Registration Form return error "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null." in new MVC 6 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I just have created a new simple MVC 6 project (with Entity Framework 7), I added the connection string to database in project.json

Then I made migration to create user tables in database.

After run application, And when go to do register new user, I receive below error after fill registration form and click on Register button:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entityType
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
```

Any One can help? Any idea to know more about this error?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the register action and see where it is failing.

Comment: It is failing here Shyju :
  var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: This is likely a bug in https://github.com/aspnet/identity. You may have better luck posting an issue there. Make sure to include more info in the issue than what you have posted here. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-issues

Comment: I have the same issue now, seems to be a bug in EF7.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred because of your model class which was not declared in the ApplicationDbContext.cs

Please add the class like `public DbSet<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }`

I added this in ApplicationDbContext.cs then error gone and save data correctly.Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

make sure the type parameter of your DbContext is like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> { }
```

Hope this help.
All the best.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had problem with my own ApplicationRole class. When changed back to IdentityRole I might login. Check your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

> services.AddIdentity< ApplicationUser, **IdentityRole**>()

here is example https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Startup.cs